# Cant insert rows into UITableView - Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I have the following code which causes the app to crash with the error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 0 into section 0, but there are only 0 rows in section 0 after the update'
```

I have tried multiple solutions as listed on StackOverflow but none can stop this error.

Tried:

- ["Attempt to insert row 0 into section 0, but there are only 0 rows in section 0 after the update" Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17005635/attempt-to-insert-row-0-into-section-0-but-there-are-only-0-rows-in-section-0)
- Others

Code:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {

    var localSearchRequest:MKLocalSearchRequest!
    var localSearch:MKLocalSearch!
    var localSearchResponse:MKLocalSearchResponse!
    var locations = [MKMapItem]()

    @available(iOS 8.0, *)
    public func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        localSearch?.cancel()
        localSearchRequest = MKLocalSearchRequest()
        localSearchRequest.naturalLanguageQuery = searchController.searchBar.text
        localSearch = MKLocalSearch(request: localSearchRequest)
        localSearch.start { (localSearchResponse, error) -> Void in
            if localSearchResponse != nil {
                let toNum = localSearchResponse?.mapItems.count ?? 0
                for i in stride(from: 0, to: toNum, by: 1) {
                    self.locations.append((localSearchResponse?.mapItems[i])!)
                    print((localSearchResponse?.mapItems[i])!)
                }
                self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: UITableViewRowAnimation(rawValue: 5)! )
            }
        }
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.locations.count;
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
        let row = indexPath.row
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.locations[row].name
        return cell
    }

    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        searchController.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Location"
        searchController.searchBar.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType(rawValue: 6)!
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        searchController.searchBar.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT:**
Using the new `localSearch.start` that ***vadian*** suggested as follows:

```
localSearch.start { (localSearchResponse, error) -> Void in
        if let response = localSearchResponse {
            self.locations.removeAll()
            for mapItem in response.mapItems {
                self.locations.append(mapItem)
                print(mapItem)
            }
            if !response.mapItems.isEmpty {
                let indexPaths = (0..<response.mapItems.count).map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }
                self.tableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .none)
            }
        }
    }
```

This still produces the same error,
`attempt to insert row 0 into section 0, but there are only 0 rows in section 0 after the update` .
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Why do you have a semicolon at the end of this line : return self.locations.count; ? And remove numberOfSections() method as you just need 1 section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code got two major issues:

- Even if the number of map items is 0 one row is inserted anyway. (That caused the error).
- If there is more than one map item also only **one** row is inserted.

Try something like this

```
    if let response = localSearchResponse { 
        for mapItem in response.mapItems { // please not those ugly C-stlye loops
           self.locations.insert(mapItem, at:0)
           print(mapItem)
        }
        if !response.mapItems.isEmpty {
            let indexPaths = (0..<response.mapItems.count).map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }
            self.tableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .none )
        }
    }
```

Note: `UITableViewRowAnimation(rawValue: 5)!` and `.none` is exactly the same, the latter is much shorter and dramatically more descriptive.

But as you don't want to use row animation at all I'd recommend

```
    if let response = localSearchResponse { 
        for mapItem in response.mapItems {
           self.locations.append(mapItem)
           print(mapItem)
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: I've decided to use your second option but although the code runs successfully, no cells appear in my UITableView. Is there another function I need to implement?

Comment: That's another question. Does `print(mapItem)` print anything?

Comment: Yes, `print(mapItem)` prints one or more MKMapItems. Sorry if my original question wasn't clear of my intended outcome.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to reload your UITableview after fetching data from network call.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614862-reloaddata

(You are inserting before the locations are fetched, and hence the tableview rows are still 0.)

Thanks
Sriram

Comment: I've added `self.tableView.reloadData()` once my rows are inserted but the cells do not appear in my UITableView (self.tableView)