# How to Inserting multiple rows in a UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying with this answer [Cant insert rows into UITableView - Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41910931/cant-insert-rows-into-uitableview-swift-3) for inserting row to the table view it is working fine but problem they showing but skip some data.

basically my problem is I have 2D array `var students : [[Student]]?` I want to insert a section that section have 4 rows.

what is the proper way showing insert rows in table view .

what I am trying so far

```
 func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return students?.count ?? 0
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return students?[section].count ?? 0
    }
```

and inserted :

```
 //scrolling down time calling this method
    func oldestState(){
        self.students?.append(getdata()) //Update students  property
        self.newsFeedTableView.beginUpdates()
        let indexPaths = (0..<(getdata().count)).map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: (self.students?.count)! - 1) }
        print(indexPaths)
        self.newsFeedTableView.insertSections([(self.students?.count)! - 1], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
        self.newsFeedTableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
        self.newsFeedTableView.endUpdates()   
    }

    func getdata() -> [Student]{
        var _students = [Student]()
        for i in  itemNumber..<(itemNumber + 4) {
            let student = Student()
            student.name = "\(i)"
             print("adding student roll number : \(student.name)")
            _students.append(student)
        }
        itemNumber  +=  4
        return _students
    }
```

[check full code](https://gist.github.com/nazmulkp/c3c866a181fa7ac6825eae5632f76c36)

here is the out put . if you see the log you will see skipping 8th - 11th row in the tableview

[image]

Comment: @vadian would you help me please

Comment: Why are you inserting rows? You could have called reloadData after changing the datasource

Comment: @AravindAR Basically  I wanted to cap the number of elements to three. When I  add element four, element one should disappear. but I spend all most 7 days . can not mange this . would help me please how can I do this .

Comment: @AravindAR Reloading the whole table when you have only changed part of the data will not be as nice, visually, as just telling the table view what you did, however since a new section is being inserted, I don't think the rows need to be inserted explicitly; simply inserting the section should be sufficient

Comment: @Paulw11 If I insert section then table view goes jerky should I share the section inserted code

Comment: Nothing here caps the elements to 3, you are just inserting sections that contain 4 elements. Have you implemented `estimatedHeightForRow`?

Comment: @Paulw11 I did but  no luck for me this problem

Comment: @Paulw11 would you help me please

Comment: @NazmulHasan when you tried with inserting only the sections, were all the values were inserted ?\

Comment: @AravindAR all value are inserted but it showing jerky when 3rd section

Comment: @AravindAR here is my previous question   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45262858/jerky-scrolling-tableview-after-insert-sections

Comment: @Paulw11  here is my previous question   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45262858/jerky-scrolling-tableview-after-insert-sections

Comment: @NazmulHasan can you try with inserting only the section with UITableViewRowAnimation to .none ?

Comment: @AravindAR I did no luck for me

Comment: @NazmulHasan is it still jerky ?

Comment: @AravindAR still jerky

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150932/discussion-between-nazmul-hasan-and-aravind-a-r).

Comment: @Paulw11 but I got one point if deleted section index 0 from table then it is goes jerky . otherwise it is working fine

Comment: Problem is there with getdata(), Its being called from somewhere else also. Thats my guess.

Comment: @MohammadSadiq no it is calling only from here

Comment: I guessed that because forget about tableview even in log yo see one print for indexpaths is skipped for every eight rows inserted its getting called once. So its got nothing to do with tableView insertion.

Comment: @MohammadSadiq would check this please full code here https://gist.github.com/nazmulkp/c3c866a181fa7ac6825eae5632f76c36

Comment: @MohammadSadiq hi man did you get anything

Answer (score 5):

I hope the problem is because `getdata()` method is called twice and thus `itemNumber` value is incremented by 4, twice

Try this:

```swift
let data = getdata()
self.students?.append(data) //Update students  property
self.newsFeedTableView.beginUpdates()
let indexPaths = (0..<(data.count)).map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: (self.students?.count)! - 1) }
```